Call to undefined method App\Controllers\Main::getRequestInput()
i try to validate input from my form, here is my controller
class Main extends BaseController
    {
        
         public function registration(){
    
            $rules = [
                 'name' => 'required'
                 ];
         
           $input = $this->getRequestInput($this->request);
           
         
            if (!$this->validateRequest($input, $rules)){
             return $this
             ->getResponse(
                 $this->validator->getErrors(),
                 ResponseInterface::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST
             );
         }

But unfortunately, I am getting:
Call to undefined method App\Controllers\Main::getRequestInput()


Where are you getting getRequestInput() from? I don't see any method named that in the CodeIgniter repo.

getRequestInput() should be an existing function in your Main.php controller, could you please show it, or is it missing?

Try this to get all POST inputs:
$input = $this->request->getPost();

Oficial documentation - CI4
Cheers!
